# Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a project and want to use the value of email form one package into another to use the value to update data but I'm getting this error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1705, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)

File "D:/Boring college/PyProject/MCB2/sign_up_2.py", line 69, in signup_button_click
    sign_up_1.SignUp.send_email()))
TypeError: send_email() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

When i enter self in send_email() it says Expected type 'SignUp' got 'SafetyQuestion' instead
SignUp is the name of class present in sign_up_1

This is the code that produces the error:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from sqlite3 import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sign_up_1
import Home_page


class SafetyQuestion(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title("Contact Book")
        self.geometry('500x400')

        self.style = Style()
        self.style.configure('Head.TFrame', background='Blue')

        self.head_frame = Frame(self, style='Head.TFrame')
        self.head_frame.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        self.style.configure('Head.TLabel', foreground='White', background='Blue', font=(NONE, 15))

        self.head_label = Label(self.head_frame, text='Select one of the following Question:',
                                style='Head.TLabel')
        self.head_label.pack(pady=3)

        val = StringVar()
        # val.set('Empty')

        self.r1 = Radiobutton(self, text='What is your nickname?', variable=val, value='What?')                
        self.r1.pack(anchor=W, pady=10, padx=10)
        self.r2 = Radiobutton(self, text='What is the name of your pet?', variable=val,
                              value='What is the name of your pet?')
        self.r2.pack(anchor=W, pady=10, padx=10)
        self.r3 = Radiobutton(self, text='What is your favourite food?', variable=val,
                              value='What is your favourite food?')
        self.r3.pack(anchor=W, pady=10, padx=10)
        self.r4 = Radiobutton(self, text='What ia your favourite Bike?', variable=val,
                              value='What ia your favourite Bike?')
        self.r4.pack(anchor=W, pady=10, padx=10)

        self.answer_frame = Frame(self, style='Head.TFrame')
        self.answer_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

        self.style.configure('Ans.TLabel', foreground='White', background='Blue', font=(NONE, 12))

        self.ans_label = Label(self.answer_frame, text='Answer:', style='Ans.TLabel')
        self.ans_label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2)

        self.style.configure('Ans.TEntry', foreground='Red', font=(NONE, 12))

        self.ans_entry = Entry(self.answer_frame, style='Ans.TEntry', width=25)
        self.ans_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=2)

        self.style.configure('Ans.TButton', forefround='Blue', font=(NONE, 12))

       self.ans_sub_button = Button(self.answer_frame, text='Sign Up', style='Ans.TButton',
                                    command=self.signup_button_click)
       self.ans_sub_button.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=10, padx=150)

    def signup_button_click(self):
        signup_con = connect('AppDatabase.db')
        signup_cur = signup_con.cursor()
        signup_cur.execute("""update LoginData 
                            set Question='{0}', Answer='{1}'
                             where Email='{1}'""".format(self.val.get(),
                                                         self.ans_entry.get(),
                                                        sign_up_1.SignUp.send_email()))
        signup_con.commit()
        signup_con.close()
        messagebox.showinfo('Successful', 'Successfully Signed Up')
        self.destroy()
        Home_page.HomePage()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    safety_question = SafetyQuestion()
    safety_question.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Appears to be a simple error. You are not actually saving the `val` variable as an instance variable. Calling `val = StringVar()` creates a onetime variable, that you lose reference to after the `__init__` method finishes running. Easy fix:

```py
self.val = StringVar()
```

Comment: plz look at the problem now. Thanks

Comment: ```sign_up_1.SignUp.send_email()))``` is not correct. If signup is a class you have to instantiate it with parenthesis. ```sign_up_1.SignUp().send_email()))```. Self is the instance of the class. When it says it's missing self that means it does not have an instance from which to pull the method